# Xamarin insights equivalent in Ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

Xamarin insights is very useful in logging error applications in xamarin. 
I am wondering if there is a same tool like xamarin insights in ionic framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$log` service provided by angular.

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log